# Complex Concatenation in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I'm working on an integration between two systems. In my Courses system there is a reference to an instructor which should be a staff member. The issue is that the Courses system allows for instructor records to be created locally (I already have a job that feeds from our Staff system to the Courses system).

A course can have more then one instructor and for business reasons a local instructor record is sometimes created as a place holder. I need to concatenate all the "real" instructors into one string, but if any of the instructors that are set for the course are not "real" instructors then I need to output an empty string. It is also possible that the course is created without any instructor assigned to it.

**Courses System**

```
Courses instructorID InstructorName  InstructorOrder
-----------------------------------------------------
ach01   1            Smith           1
ach01   2            Brown           2
phy01   3            James           1
sci01   1            Smith           1
sci01   4            Doe             2
acc01   NULL         NULL            NULL
```

**Staff System**

```
ID   LastName
--------------
1    Smith
2    Brown
3    James
```

**Output**

```
Course  Instructors
-------------------------
arc01   'Smith, Brown'
phy01   'James'
sci01   ''
acc01   ''
```

This is the SQL I came up with, but I would like to know if there is a better way of getting the same results

```
select courseID,
       isnull(case max(case when x.rn = 1 then isnull(lastname, '-|-') else '' end) when '-|-' then NULL else max(case when x.rn = 1 then lastname else '' end) end +
              case max(case when x.rn = 2 then isnull(lastname, '-|-') else '' end) when '-|-' then NULL else max(case when x.rn = 2 then ', ' + lastname else '' end) end +
              case max(case when x.rn = 3 then isnull(lastname, '-|-') else '' end) when '-|-' then NULL else max(case when x.rn = 3 then ', ' + lastname else '' end) end +
              case max(case when x.rn = 4 then isnull(lastname, '-|-') else '' end) when '-|-' then NULL else max(case when x.rn = 4 then ', ' + lastname else '' end) end
              , '') Instructors
from (select courseID, s.lastname,
             ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by courseID order by InstructorOrder) rn
      from Courses c left join  
           Active_Staff s on c.instructorID = s.ID 
      ) x
group by courseID
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200376/concatenate-with-order-preservation).

Comment: Thank, HABO. The sort order is not the issue. That's taken care of in SQL2005 by using the Row_Number() OVER() functions. I would like to know if there is a better way to hand all the CASE statements in order to make sure that all instructors are in the staff system.

Comment: Will there be never more than four instructors for one  course?

Comment: Four is the max we allow. There won't be more than that in the system.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a bit different syntax but the query will essentially do exactly the same as the query you already have. I don't expect there will be a performance difference at all.

```
select P.Courses,
       case when S.Instructors like '%NOSTAFF%' then '' else S.Instructors end as Instructors
from (
     select C.Courses,
            isnull(S.LastName, 'NOSTAFF') as LastName,
            row_number() over(partition by C.Courses order by C.InstructorOrder) as rn
     from Courses as C
       left outer join Staff as S
         on C.instructorID = S.ID
     ) as T
pivot (
      max(T.LastName) for T.rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
      ) as P
cross apply
      (
      select isnull(P.[1], '')+isnull(P.[2], '')+isnull(P.[3], '')+isnull(P.[4], '') as Instructors
      ) as S
```

Comment: I like the method, but I think the implementation could be simplified. It seems you could remove *all* the ISNULLs you've currently got there and replace the CASE in the main SELECT with just `ISNULL(S.Instructors, '')`.

Comment: @AndriyM Not sure how you figure that. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b18ce/1). There will be null values coming out of the pivot for two reasons. First if there is no match in `Staff` and second if there are less than 4 instructors for a Course.

Comment: Indeed, the latter case was precisely what I missed, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit complicated (and perhaps it is) but it gets the job done:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Courses c
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Active_Staff s ON c.instructorID = s.ID
)
,CTE2 AS
(  
    SELECT  CourseID, 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + LastName 
              FROM   CTE1 c2 
              WHERE  c2.CourseID = c1.CourseID 
              ORDER BY c2.InstructorOrder
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')  LastNames
    FROM  CTE1 c1 
    GROUP BY CourseID
)
SELECT
    CourseID,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE1  WHERE LastName IS NULL AND CTE1.CourseID = Cte2.CourseID) THEN '' ELSE LastNames END AS Instructors
FROM CTE2
```

Basically, we get all the string concatenated first - using STUFF and FOR XML PATH combination and then just replace with empty string those that have at least one 'dummy' instructor.

Here is [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3035e/1)

Comment: Thank. This takes about 30x longer to run on my DB than the query I have. My query takes 2 seconds to run and this one take around 60 seconds. I'm looking to run this query in an AJAX call. I would like to bring the query down to 1 second or a few milliseconds.

Comment: Hm, I didn't expect that much of performance hit. If I get the time I'll check for faster solution.

However - please note that this query will run correctly for any number of instructors per class. and not for only up to 4.